# PHP file writing problem

Tags: php

I'm trying to write to a file in PHP to cache the output of a small portion of code.

```
        ob_start();
        echo "Hello";
     $fp = fopen("cache/ttcache.php", 'w');
        fwrite($fp, ob_get_contents());
        fclose($fp);
        ob_end_flush();
```

The file exists and is blank. The fwrite function points to the correct location. It just doesn't write.

Any help?

Comment: What happens if you simply echo ob_get_contents()?

Comment: Can you show some minimal code that reproduces the problem? Something that actually produces output, i.e. where the `// my code that creates an output` is filled in.

Comment: ob_get_contents() holds the correct data, I just checked it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to write first small word or sentence first.

```
fwrite($fp, 'hello')
```

Also check your file permission's should be `writable`.

Comment: It doesn't write a word, I think you're correct in that this is a permissions problem. I'll make it writable if it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `ob_get_contents()` is really not empty. Then try

```
fflush($fp);
```

right before `fclose()`.